# How to determine an alphabetically greater list or number?

Tags: java, algorithm

I encountered an algorithm problem with which I need to find alphabetically greater list, say 9,10,9,8,7 is greater than 8,9,10,9,8

I have a question on the alphabetical order for numbers. Is 9 an alphabetically greater number or 10?

In Java, I use "9".compareTo("10"), the result is 8, and "2".compareTo("11111") is 1.

Which one is alphabetically greater?

Comment: If the result is greater than `0`, the caller (`"9"` here) is greater than its argument (`"10"` here), if it is less than `0`, it is less than, if it is `0`, the two are equal.

Comment: Note that this is programming language specific question - please add the language that you used.

Comment: When in doubt search the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)